# OnClickListener not firing in fragment

Tags: java, android, onclick

I've already searched through the forum for answers, but I couldn't find any question that completely matches my situation.

I'm having a problem firing an onclicklistener. The same piece of code works in other parts of application, which confuses me.

This is my code:

```
private static  final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGES = 1;
TextView filepath_name;
EditText varighed, navn;
Spinner genre, kategori;
Button uploadImg, opret_knap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    uploadImg = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.billede_button);
    opret_knap = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addOpskrift);
    varighed = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.opskrift_varighed);
    navn = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.opskrift_navn);
    genre = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.opskrift_genre);
    kategori = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.opskrift_kategori);

    filepath_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.billede_path);
    uploadImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
             startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGES);
         }

    });

    opret_knap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Tilføjopskrift();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

And the XML

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/billede_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Tilføj billede"
        />
<TextView android:id="@+id/billede_path"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="32dp"
          android:layout_gravity="center" />

<Button android:id="@+id/addOpskrift"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:text="Opret"/>
```

Comment: What is this method? "Tilføjopskrift();"? I wouldnt recommend you to use special characters just like "ø"

Comment: It is a method that adds something into a arraylist, I've changed the name but no changes

Comment: I think you didn't post your whole XML, cause I don't see the definition of `billede_button`

Comment: Changing the name of the method will not debug any logic, I think... That recommendation targets something different: international readability

Comment: I think you must change your method name.

Answer (score 2):

In your XML you have given id `opret_knap` to you Button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/opret_knap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:text="Opret"/>
```

But you are accessing it with `addOpskrift`

Change

```
opret_knap = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addOpskrift);
```

to

```
 opret_knap = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.opret_knap);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it couple of times while trying to fix the issue. They match now, but yet it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are not specifying the layout your fragment should access.

Instead of:

```
super.onCreateView()
```

Use

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, container, false);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your not instanciate correctely the new view. 
You need use:

`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_file_name, container, false);`

instead of:

`View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);`.

Just copy and paste.

```
private static  final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGES = 1;
TextView filepath_name;
EditText varighed, navn;
Spinner genre, kategori;
Button uploadImg, opret_knap;


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_file_name, container, false);
    uploadImg = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.billede_button);
    opret_knap = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addOpskrift);
    varighed = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.opskrift_varighed);
    navn = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.opskrift_navn);
    genre = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.opskrift_genre);
    kategori = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.opskrift_kategori);

    filepath_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.billede_path);
    uploadImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
             startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGES);
         }

    });

    opret_knap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Tilføjopskrift();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```